# Recommend Linux Live CD/DVD with R installed

Tags: linux, r, live-cd

Well, the title is pretty much self-explanatory. I've seen [Quantian](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/quantian.html), but it's pretty outdated, there's [UberStudent](http://uberstudent.org/)... anything else worth mentioning? I'm especially interested in your experiences with Live CD/DVD's, regarding computational speed, usability and stuff like that. Links, advices, anything that you find useful is more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scientific Linux:
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=scientific

And this is a version of Scientific Linux that fit in one CD: http://www.livecd.ethz.ch/

What about making your own Ubuntu LiveCD?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Another thread on [How to make a live CD/DVD from your harddisk installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting SL. I've left the custom build Live CD/DVD as my last alternative... Probably Ubuntu with Remastersys.

Answer (score 1):

I've booted [Knoppix Math](http://knoppix-math.org/) before and found it reasonably usable. I can't really say how well it's maintained, as it's been  a little while.

EDIT: Cool, it looks like it's still being actively maintained!

Comment: I wasn't aware of this one, thanks. It's poorly documented, though... at least for a non-Japanese... =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method for rolling your own Ubuntu liveCD: [UCK](http://uck.sourceforge.net/) (Ubunutu Customization Kit) along with a [howto](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/easily-create-custom-ubuntu-live-cd.html) I found.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I need custom-build Live Linux distro with R, not a tool for Linux customisation... I've combed down the Internets Googling for Linux customisation apps, this post seems quite useful: http://goo.gl/CpfOG
Anyway... there's no need for custom Linux if there's already a good tool available!

Comment: Your post is confusing. The customization is that you can add default packages to the install cd. Thus you can add R and any other packages you need to the installer.